# this web page has redirect loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cookies, session-cookies

I am doing a test example for login page in php (I deliberately want unprotected the code against security issues such as SQL injection or session hijacking for learning purposes). and I want to use cookies. 
The index page looks like this. simply a user name and password:
[image]

When I try to login, I get this page:
[image]

Can you please help me what this problem that caused this error?

At the beginning of the index.php I used the following php code:

```
   <?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php");
}
?>
```

Then, in the login.php, the following code was used:

```
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Selecting Database
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "mydbname");
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from users where password='$password' AND userName='$username'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

Then, in the profile.php, I used this code:

```
    <?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Home Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="profile">
<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
<b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
This is the content of session.php

```
    <?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "mydbname");
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysqli_query($connection,"select userName from login where userName='$user_check'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['userName'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have `session_start();` anywhere, if that is the case then this will always remain a redirect loop from one page to another

Comment: what is the content of `session.php`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe add

```
session_start();
```

before $_SESSION value

Comment: I used `session_start( );` in the session.php which is included.

Comment: check two things, index.php is included session_start();? var_dump($_POST) is right post data?  $rows == 1 is true?